# Jquery countdown timer with php not performing as expected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on a jquery/php countdown timer and the output is not as expected

Here is the below code

```php
<p id='FeedExpire-".$id."' class='FeedExpire' style='display:inline-block;'>".$expires_by_cleaned_new."</p>
```

Picking up the innerhtml contents of a p tag and running it in a loop to display the count down timer for each element in jquery

```
var x = setInterval(function() { 
$('.FeedExpire').each(function () { 
   alert(document.querySelector('#'+this.id).innerHTML);    
   var deadline = new Date(document.querySelector('#'+this.id).innerHTML).getTime();
});
```

But not getting the result as expected .i get the expected results and it changes in instant(Screenshots attached below )

Complete code below

Expected result

[image]

Error

[image]

```
$( document ).ready(function() {            
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://192.168.1.11/Retrivedataforhomefeed.php",
       //data: {email:email,userId:userId,displayName:displayName,givenName:givenName,},
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
           var results=data;
           document.querySelector('.Homefeedstart').innerHTML = results;
           //alert(document.getElementsById('DBPostExpireBy-1').innerHTML);

           var x = setInterval(function() { 
               $('.FeedExpire').each(function () { 
                   alert(document.querySelector('#'+this.id).innerHTML);   
                   var deadline = new Date(document.querySelector('#'+this.id).innerHTML).getTime();
                   var now = new Date().getTime(); 
                   var t = deadline - now; 
                   var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
                   var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60)); 
                   var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); 
                   var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); 
                   document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "; 
                   if (t < 0) { 
                       clearInterval(x); 
                       document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = "EXPIRED"; 
                   } 
               });
           }, 1000); 
           //});
           //var FeedDatareturned=$(".FeedExpire").attr('id');
           //alert(FeedDatareturned); 
       }
   });
});
```

```php
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, origin, content-type,');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    include("DatabaseConnection.php");
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posted_data");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $terms = array();
    foreach($row as $output) {
        $id=$output['Id'];
        $user_comment = $output['User_comment'];
        $expires_by =$output['Post_expires_by'];
        $expires_by_cleaned = substr($expires_by, 3);
        $expires_by_cleaned_new= substr($expires_by_cleaned, 0, strpos($expires_by_cleaned, 'GMT'));
        $Posted_by = $output['Posted_by'];
        echo"
            <div class='FeedBox' id='FeedBox-".$id."'>
                <img src='img/report.jpg' id='FeedReport-".$id."' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='float:right;'>  
                <img src='img/img_avatar.png' id='FeedImage-".$id."' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='border-radius: 50%;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px;'>
                <div id='FeedHeader-".$id."' class='FeedHeader'>".$Posted_by."</div> <div id='FeedRadius-".$id."'>Within:100 meters</div>
            <div class='UserComment' id='Data-".$id."'>".$user_comment."</div>
            <div id='HelpExpireText-".$id."' style='display:inline-block;'>lend a hand by:</div><div class='DBPostExpireBy' id='DBPostExpireBy-".$id."' style='display:none;'>".$expires_by_cleaned_new."</div><p id='FeedExpire-".$id."' class='FeedExpire' style='display:inline-block;'></p><div class='ReadMore' id='ReadMore-".$id."' style='display:inline-block;float:right;padding-top:16px;padding-right:5px;' onclick='Nextpage(this);'>Discuss</div></div>";
    }

?>
```

Not sure where i am going wrong please advise

Console.log(deadline) screenshot below

[image: console.log(deadline)]

Comment: Try `console.log(deadline);`. What does that output?

Comment: Why not just ask about the formatting? This is not a PHP question unless there are errors in the PHP, then it is not a jQuery question

Comment: Please try `$('.FeedExpire').each(function () { 
                               var deadline = new Date(this.innerText.trim()).getTime();            `

Comment: @mplungjan tried the above still getting the same output(no changes).

Comment: @nickbellavi See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this. No need to change the PHP, assuming the timestamp is in milliseconds
You need to convert the timestamp to an INT

You do NOT want to clear the interval until ALL timers are expired. You could have a timer per post or just keep it running

```
success: function(data) {
       var results=data;
       $('.Homefeedstart').html(results);
       startTimers():
```

add this elsewhere in the script outside the ajax

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2)
const aSecond = 1000;
const aMinute = aSecond * 60
const anHour = aMinute * 60;
const aDay = anHour * 24;
let x;

function startTimers() {
  clearInterval(x)
  x = setInterval(function() {
    $('.DBPostExpireBy').each(function() {
      let deadline = new Date(+$.trim($(this).text())).getTime();
      let now = new Date().getTime();
      let t = deadline - now;
      let days = Math.floor(t / aDay);
      let hours = Math.floor((t % (aDay)) / (anHour));
      let minutes = Math.floor((t % (anHour)) / (aMinute));
      let seconds = Math.floor((t % (aMinute)) / aSecond);
      let time = t < 0 ? "Expired" : days + "d " + pad(hours) + "h " + pad(minutes) + "m " + pad(seconds) + "s "
      $(this).next().html(time);
    });
  }, 1000);
}

startTimers(); // MOVE this to inside the success
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='FeedBox' id='FeedBox-1'>
  <img src='img/report.jpg' id='FeedReport-1' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='float:right;'>
  <img src='img/img_avatar.png' id='FeedImage-1' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='border-radius: 50%;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px;'>
  <div id='FeedHeader1' class='FeedHeader'>Posted_by A</div>
  <div id='FeedRadius-1'>Within:100 meters</div>
  <div class='UserComment' id='Data-1'>User A comment</div>
  <div id='HelpExpireText-1' style='display:inline-block;'>lend a hand by:</div>
  <div class='DBPostExpireBy' id='DBPostExpireBy-1' style='display:none;'>1581501796895</div>
  <p id='FeedExpire-1' class='FeedExpire' style='display:inline-block;'></p>
  <div class='ReadMore' id='ReadMore-1' style='display:inline-block;float:right;padding-top:16px;padding-right:5px;' onclick='Nextpage(this);'>Discuss</div>
</div>
<div class='FeedBox' id='FeedBox-2'>
  <img src='img/report.jpg' id='FeedReport-2' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='float:right;'>
  <img src='img/img_avatar.png' id='FeedImage-2' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='border-radius: 50%;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px;'>
  <div id='FeedHeader1' class='FeedHeader'>Posted_by A</div>
  <div id='FeedRadius-1'>Within:100 meters</div>
  <div class='UserComment' id='Data-1'>User A comment</div>
  <div id='HelpExpireText-1' style='display:inline-block;'>lend a hand by:</div>
  <div class='DBPostExpireBy' id='DBPostExpireBy-1' style='display:none;'>1581501896895</div>
  <p id='FeedExpire-1' class='FeedExpire' style='display:inline-block;'></p>
  <div class='ReadMore' id='ReadMore-1' style='display:inline-block;float:right;padding-top:16px;padding-right:5px;' onclick='Nextpage(this);'>Discuss</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes if one of the timestamp expired would cause all the timers to stop .Converting the timestamp(miliseconds) to INT did the trick thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: Yeah but also please use my script since it is much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

**please make sure you that you are getting all the data correctly from the server**
because the code works when the date is added manually

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

try to update your php as follow:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, origin, content-type,');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    include("DatabaseConnection.php");
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posted_data");
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $terms = array();
    foreach($row as $output) {
        $id=$output['Id'];
        $user_comment = $output['User_comment'];
        $expires_by =$output['Post_expires_by'];
        $expires_by_cleaned = substr($expires_by, 3);
        $expires_by_cleaned_new= substr($expires_by_cleaned, 0, strpos($expires_by_cleaned, 'GMT'));
        $Posted_by = $output['Posted_by'];
        echo"
            <div class='FeedBox' id='FeedBox-".$id."'>
                <img src='img/report.jpg' id='FeedReport-".$id."' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='float:right;'>  
                <img src='img/img_avatar.png' id='FeedImage-".$id."' alt='Avatar' width='50px' height='50px' style='border-radius: 50%;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px;'>
                <div id='FeedHeader-".$id."' class='FeedHeader'>".$Posted_by."</div> <div id='FeedRadius-".$id."'>Within:100 meters</div>
            <div class='UserComment' id='Data-".$id."'>".$user_comment."</div>
            <div id='HelpExpireText-".$id."' style='display:inline-block;'>lend a hand by:</div><div class='DBPostExpireBy' id='DBPostExpireBy-".$id."' style='display:none;'>".$expires_by_cleaned_new."</div><p id='".$id."' class='FeedExpire' style='display:inline-block;'></p><div class='ReadMore' id='ReadMore-".$id."' style='display:inline-block;float:right;padding-top:16px;padding-right:5px;' onclick='Nextpage(this);'>Discuss</div></div>";
    }

?>
```

and your deadline as:

```
var deadline = new Date(document.querySelector('#DBPostExpireBy-'+this.id).innerHTML).getTime();
```

Comment: Hi Moneer ,double checked on that too but still doesn't seem to work .Maybe going wrong somewhere in the each function in jquery (But unable to figure it out )

Comment: can you mark the answer as the right answer, please